# Rails text fields without submit button (auto-submit on input change)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am writing a Rails application that has the user entering a 1-digit number, and that number is compared to an "answer" in the database to see if it is correct. I want the comparison to happen instantaneously, as soon as the user enters the number into the field I want the comparison to happen right away.

The way I currently have it setup is the user has to enter the number and click a submit button to submit the form which links to the controller action that checks if it's correct. But I want it to do it automatically on user input, without the need of a submit button.

My form currently:

```
<%= form_with :controller => "tests", :action => "check_answer", remote: true, local: true, method: 'get' do |f| %>
    <%= f.number_field :answer, :value => '' %>  
    <%= f.submit 'Submit' %>
<% end %>
```

Ideally I would like to do this without the use of JavaScript or jQuery, but can use it if need be. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see a way to do this without js. Try something like:

```
<%= f.number_field :answer, value: '', onchange: "this.form.submit()" %>
```

Or maybe use `onkeyup` instead of `onchange`.

Comment: `onkeyup` worked, the form submits when input is entered. Is there a way I can get it to do another function instead of `this.form.submit()` on key up? Like can I link it to a controller action or something? Or can I make it a custom js function somewhere?

Comment: I was able to add a javascript script function on `onkeyup` which worked great. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Stimulus auto save](https://www.stimulus-components.com/docs/stimulus-rails-autosave/), Stimulus is the default js library on rails 7.